# JQuery Floating Boxes of Different Size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 9 floating boxes on a page with 3 columns, generated from this JQ script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { 
        $("ul.connectedSortable").sortable({handle:'.kpiValueContainer', connectWith:'trysomethingelse', placeholder:'ui-state-highlight', revert: true});
    }); 
</script>
```

The columns are in fact "ul" and the boxes are "li", so there are 3 boxes "li's" in each column "ul's".

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="boxContainer">
   <ul id="column1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="box1"></li>
      <li class="box2"></li>
      <li class="box3"></li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="column2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="box4"></li>
      <li class="box5"></li>
      <li class="box6"></li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="column3" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="box7"></li>
      <li class="box8"></li>
      <li class="box9"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

My question is, how can I have boxes of different size in the same column without messing up the whole scene =)

My placeholder should match the current moving box, ie it should "know" it's a box of size A, B or C and thus adapt to the box size.

My CSS:

```
.boxContainer
{
    margin:0px;
    width:1100px;
    height:auto;}

.column1, .column2, .column3 { 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0 10px 0 0px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:300px;}

html>body .column1 li, .column2 li, .column3 li { 
    height:auto;
    width:300px;}

.column1 li, .column2 li, .column3 li {
    margin:50px 0 0 0px;
    height:255px;
    width:300px;}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think all you are missing is `forcePlaceholderSize:true` in your sortable definition.

That, combined with `placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'` will make placeholders that are the same size as the box you are moving...

Here's an example of it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Y5fzX/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But I'm sorry it did not solve my problem, since I have boxes of different "width" and not "height".

I'm thinking about using "grid" instead of columns?

What you say?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it it is exactly what you are searching for, but have you tried setting the height/width of the placeholder to the height/width of the currently dragged element in sortable.start()?

`$(selector).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.width());
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    }
});`